# Oracle JDeveloper - build

Tags: oracle, build, jdeveloper

I am new to Oracle JDeveloper and Oracle ADF framework. If I do some changes in java files, I do stop oc4j and rebuild in project level, and starting it again. Is that the right way of doing it or do we have any partial/swap build options there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deploy will trigger the oc4j to reload any changed objects, including jsp and classes (by checksum or mod date, not quite certain). Most j2ee server implementations (that I know of) provide this functionality. Typically you should only have to reload if you make web.xml changes, or if you are getting some type of session problems, etc.